# How would a psychopath deem their actions?

Tags: clinical-psychology, moral-psychology

I understand that a psychopath experiences diminished or non-existent empathy and remorse as well as dis-inhibition meaning that they have a certain 'meanness' and a poor impulse control.

I am interested in how they would deem the actions that they perform as a result of their condition. **Would they justify their actions as being morally correct?** The right thing to do, so to speak.